# Compose many characters from text to string in C

Tags: string, character, reverse

How can I compose many characters to one string so that I can reverse that string later?
I read characters with getchar() from stdin. I print it in a loop like this:

```
  do 
  {
    character = getchar();
    printf("%c", character);
  }
 while(character != EOF)
```

But I have to print it reversed. How can I do that?

Comment: Why are you trying to achieve that ? 
You can type the reversed string directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the characters in a buffer (`char buffer[255]` for example).

Comment: Hm..that doesn't work because I don't know how many characters I have to read. So I can't define the buffer size up front.

Comment: @user2966420 you may know a maximum input size. You're not going to input 1 megabyte of data by hand.

Comment: Okay, my fault. The typed in text is a input.txt file. I'm working with dynamic memory management, but thats only for the memory of course. I can't say how much text is in the file.

Comment: In c++ you can use dynamical arrays like vector. In C you'll have to implement that by yourself. The usual way is that you start with something sized x (say 100 bytes) and whenever you reach the limit allocate another buffer, twice as large and copy everything there.